# How to live track of progress in terminal over portal?

Tags: linux, terminal, brute-force, portal, handshake

So, I have this question that I didnt try to make beforeand was not sure how to search and what to do.

**To give little background :** Currently me and couple of my friend trying to building drone hacking platform which have rasperry pi on it. Our plan is to established wifi connection with base station and have a portal running on pi that will trigger some scripts including wpa bruteforcing. But for brute force the captured handshake will forward to base station and bruteforcing process will start on that machine.

**My question is** we need to **be able to live track of the bruteforcing process over the local built portal** so when we go to that portal we can see the percentage of progress and etc.

However, I didnt do such a think like this before and have no idea and/or dont know that and how to research for that. Therefore i**f anyone can give a lead or some idea** I would appriciate it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Write to a file and then track each change using `tail -f <filename>`. You can do this remotely over ssh

Comment: First of all thanks for advice, but I was wondering how to show it on the web portal like the tail -f command result is there plugin or something like that ?